# PouchDB security

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

What's the best security practice to follow while using PouchDB on the client-side to access a remote server?

The example on https://pouchdb.com/getting-started.html syncs with the remote server with the code:

```
var remoteCouch = 'http://user:pass@mname.example.com/todos';
```

The problem is I probably don't want the user to see the plaintext password with a file they can download -- even if that file is shown to the authenticated users only.

Please advise. Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 8):

Here's a [really good article](https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/blob/master/docs/recipes.md) regarding all things auth for CouchDB.

I've got a production server with CouchDB configured to use HTTP over localhost but external requests require HTTPS redirected via [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org/index.html) to CouchDB.

On the client I use PouchDB to maintain a local, replicated db.  As part of the handshake to establish communication with CouchDB over HTTPS, the software acquires CouchDB credentials from another server - the credentials are never stored client side.

[pouchdb-authentication](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication) is a good plugin, but I've found it better to handle auth personally.

Answer (score 2):

Every site user should have his own CouchDB user. As @onno suggests, use HTTPS and the user's login credentials to access CouchDB. Passwords should never be available in client-side JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

This depends on your remote server. If you use a CouchDB server, you could configure it to communicate only via SSL (HTTPS), see the [docs](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146) for details.

If you don't want to expose your CouchDB server directly to the internet, you could also hide it behind a reverse-proxy, e.g. an Apache server with the mod_proxy extension and SSL enabled.

Comment: Using SSL does not help against an attacker who can read the password from the javascript source